# Actualizar un ASPxGridView con diferente DataSource y diferentes columnas

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp, devexpress, aspx

Tengo un `ASPxGridView` vacio creado en la vista que se llena al hacer click en un boton. Lo que necesito es que al hacer click si ya se estaba mostrando una tabla y seleccione otra diferente que se actualice en el `ASPxGridView`.

Fragmentos de codigo:

Vista

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="gridReportes" runat="server" Settings-HorizontalScrollBarMode="Auto" Styles-Cell-CssClass="textAlignLeft" ClientInstanceName="grid" EnablePagingGestures="False"
     CssClass="grid-view" Width="100%">
    <SettingsBehavior AllowEllipsisInText="true" AllowSort="false" />
    <SettingsResizing ColumnResizeMode="Control" />
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

C#

```
    gridReportes.Columns.Clear();
    gridReportes.DataSource = null;
    gridReportes.DataSource = ds3.Tables[0]; //ds3 es un DataSet donde esta almacenada la tabla a mostrar
    gridReportes.DataBind();
```

Al `DataSet` le coloque un punto de interrupción y efectivamente aparecen los nuevos datos pero no se refresca en el GridView. He investigado y segun con el `Columns.Clear() y DataSource = null` ya se elimina lo que estaba anteriormente en el GridView, pero no esta funcionando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de varias pruebas la solución fue agregarle al `ASPxGridView` la opción `AutoGenerateColumns` y establecerla en `True`.

```
 gridReportes.Columns.Clear();
 gridReportes.DataSource = null;
 gridReportes.AutoGenerateColumns = true; //Esta linea de aca
 gridReportes.DataSource = ds3.Tables[0];
 gridReportes.DataBind();
```

Despues de limpiar las Columnas y el DataSource y antes de agregar el nuevo DataSource al GridView.